# How can I ignore empty lines before, after, and inside an equation environment?

Tags: spacing, equations, paragraphs, displaystyle

I would like an equation environment that doesn't care about empty lines. Normally, empty lines before and after equation start a new paragraph, resulting in additional vertical spacing around the display equation. Empty lines inside the equation environment cause a compilation error:

```
Text above
                    % <- Empty line causes additional spacing
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
                    % <- Empty line causes error
x &= y \\
                    % <- Empty line causes error
y &= z
                    % <- Empty line causes error
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
                    % <- Empty line causes additional spacing
Text below
```

Comment: Perhaps you use blank lines to visually arrange and organize your document input.  If so, just get in the habit of placing a lone `%` on the otherwise blank lines.  It looks virtually the same, and you don't need to modify LaTeX at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, that conflicts with paragraph motion in Vim. It's also more work. That said, I agree that this is the recommended solution for the majority of users.

Comment: you have not provided a test document and your fragment has no blank lines that would generate an erroneous `\par` as they are all commented out.

Comment: It is not smart idea adapt LaTeX to specific of your editor. By this you make problems to others who use other LateX editors.

Comment: @Zarko I think there is a misunderstanding here. This question is not specific to an editor. I edit LaTeX source often and don't want to spend additional time maintaining empty comments as a workaround for supporting empty lines, e.g. inside equation environments. This will also not cause problems to other editors.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed as opinion-based. The question poses a clear technical problem with a code example. What is opinion-based is not the technical question but the recommendation by some users against wanting what I want to achieve.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution to this? I couldn't understand the answer below. Many thanks

Comment: @Confounded Yes, the example code in my answer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

- **Empty lines before.** Once LateX processed a `\par` it can't be removed. Instead, we check if we're at the beginning of a new paragraph with `\ifvmode` and then set parskip to zero and compensate for the empty line above with negative space.
- **Empty lines after.**  We can prevent the `\par` after an environment from being written using `\@gobble\par`, which ignores both spaces and a line break that might follow the equation environment. For more details, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269907/61219).
- **Empty lines inside.** To hide empty lines from amsmath, we change `\endlinechar` [to a space character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16462/61219). This should not affect the equation otherwise, because spaces are ignored in math mode. I'm unsure why a nested command is needed but it does work.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\xapptocmd\normalsize{%
\abovedisplayskip=.8em plus .2em minus .2em
\belowdisplayskip=.6em plus .1em minus .1em
\abovedisplayshortskip=.8em plus .2em minus .2em
\belowdisplayshortskip=.6em plus .1em minus .1em
}{}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removeParBefore}{\ifvmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\setlength{\parskip}{0ex}\fi}
\newcommand{\removeParAfter}{\@ifnextchar\par\@gobble\relax}
\newcommand{\eq}{\begingroup\removeParBefore\endlinechar=32 \eqinner}
\newcommand{\eqinner}[1]{\endlinechar=32%
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}#1\end{aligned}\end{equation}\endgroup\removeParAfter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\eq{

x &= y \\


y &= z

}


\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: equation environment with removed spaces]

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not work. You had not provided an example so i added one. Note that this is using shortdisplayskip even though the final line of the text is long so the spacing at the top is wrong.  Also unlike a blank line before or in an equation, a blank line after an equation is not an error it is the mechanism to mark the following text as starting a paragraph, which isn't possible if you remove the `\par` unless you use unnatural markup like `\par\par` so only one is removed.

Comment: also if you remove the comments so your lines are empty then you get `! Missing $ inserted` errors

Comment: it also sets `\parskip` to 0pt for the rest of the document, even if it was non-zero initially.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these things and improving the example. It should all be working now. By the way, I would say that none of the default behavior here is an error on the side of LaTeX. It was just an inconvenience to me.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question as posted, it is advertised as allowing a more flexible _input_ form ignoring blank lines but it adversely affects the layout of the _whole document_ even if the `\eq` macro is not used.  Try a document `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}aaaaa\begin{equation}  1=1\end{equation} aaaa \end{document}` You are changing the spacing around all display math. the `\eq` macro will still give missing `$` errors in `\parbox` and similar constructs, and the `\eq` macro suppresses page breaking before the equation.

Comment: Thanks again for pointing out these limitations. Do you have a suggestion for fixing them?

Comment: no: a blank line being end of paragraph is a fundamental syntax feature of the language.